# Extension Borel measure on $[0, T]$

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, borel-measures, signed-measures

Suppose that for every $T > 0$ we have a finite signed measure $\mu_T : \mathcal{B}([0, T]) \to (-\infty, \infty)$ and that for all $T_1 < T_2$ we have that $\mu_{T_2}(A) = \mu_{T_1}(A)$ for all $A \in \mathcal{B}([0, T_1])$. Can we show that there exists a unique (probably $\sigma$-finite) signed measure $\mu : \mathcal{B}([0, \infty)) \to [-\infty, \infty]$ such that the restriction to $\mathcal{B}([0, T])$ for each $T > 0$ is equal to $\mu_T$?

My first thought would be to use Carathéodory's extension theorem on the positive and real parts of $\mu_T$, however $\mathcal{B}([0, T])$ is not a ring on $[0, \infty)$, even if we add the complements and extend it properly, I'm not sure if it is a ring either.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think so. Let $\lambda$ be the standard Borel measure and for $T\geq 0$ consider $$\mu_T(A)=\lambda(A\cap [0,1))-\lambda(A\cap [1,2))+\lambda(A\cap [2,3))-\lambda(A\cap [3,4))+\dots +(-1)^{\lfloor T \rfloor}\lambda(A\cap [\lfloor T \rfloor, T]).$$ Then $\{\mu_T\}_T$ satisfies your consistency conditions,  but if $\mu$ is any extension we would have $\mu(\bigcup\limits_{n\in \mathbb{N}} [2n, 2n+1))=\infty$ and $\mu(\bigcup\limits_{n\in \mathbb{N}} [2n+1, 2n+2))=-\infty$. This is a contradiction since a signed measure cannot attain both of the values $\infty$ and $-\infty$ at the same time.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. This indeed looks like a genuine counterexample. I struggled with it myself, and in the end I changed the theorem to look for an extension of the total variation measure. For that I used that $$\bigcup_{T > 0} \mathcal{B}([0, T])$$ is a ring on which I can uniquely define the measure and then extend with Carathédory's Extension Theorem. However, your answer makes me doubt the correctness. Would you say that this also goes wrong for extension of the total variation measure?

Comment: Because the total variation measures $|\mu_T|$ again satisfy the property that $|\mu_{T_2}|_{|\mathcal{B}([0, T_1])}=|\mu_{T_1}|$ for $T_1 < T_2$ Carathédory's Extension Theorem certainly applies here (for example , for the measures I defined in my answer the extension would just be $\lambda_{|[0,\infty)}$). The issue with the original question was that we were dealing with signed measures. It may still be that your original question has a positive answer if $\sup\{|\mu_T|([0,T])\}<\infty$... I'll try to investigate further.